# Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 13, in <module> File "<string>", line 5, in max_min IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, lista

alguien que me pueda instruir con este codigo, mi objetivo es hallar el mayor y menor de una lista con una función

```
def max_min(list):       #Funcion
    max = -1000
    min = 1000
    for i in (0,len(list)):
        if list[i]<min:        #halla el menor
            min = list[i]
            aux1 = i
        if list[i]>max:         #halla el mayor
            max = list[i]
            aux2 = i
    print(f"El numero menor es: {min} en el orden {aux1} y el numero mayor es: {max} en el orden {aux2}")
list = [2,5,4,7,9,10,3,5,1,4,5]
max_min(list)
```

Me manda este error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in max_min
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: en primer lugar estas usando palabras reservadas de Python :/ y te falto el `range`, es `for i in range(0,len(list))`

Comment: @Christian el 0 sobra range comienza por defecto en 0

Comment: @tincopasan cierto :D

Answer (score 2):

Haber en primer lugar no uses palabras reservadas como nombres de variables, ya que a veces se puede confundir con el propio objeto. Luego tu error es la falta de la palabra reservada `range` para el ciclo `for` puesto esto indica que se itera en un rango.

```py
def max_min(lista):       #Funcion
    max = -1000
    min = 1000
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if lista[i]<min:        #halla el menor
            min = lista[i]
            aux1 = i
        if lista[i]>max:         #halla el mayor
            max = lista[i]
            aux2 = i
    print(f"El numero menor es: {min} en el orden {aux1} y el numero mayor es: {max} en el orden {aux2}")

lista = [2,5,4,7,9,10,3,5,1,4,5]
max_min(lista)
```

**resultado**

```
El numero menor es: 1 en el orden 8 y el numero mayor es: 10 en el orden 5
```

Una opción simplificada seria utilizar las funciones `min()` y `max()` para obtener el mínimo y máximo respectivamente, y para obtener el indice se hace con el metodo `list.index()`.

```py
def max_min(lista):       #Funcion
    maxi = max(lista) #obtenemos el numero maximo
    mini = min(lista) #obtenemos el numero minimo
    ind_max = lista.index(maxi) #obtenemos la posicion del numero
    ind_min = lista.index(mini) #obtenemos la posicion del numero
    print(f"El numero menor es: {mini} en el orden {ind_min} y el numero mayor es: {maxi} en el orden {ind_max}")
lista = [2,5,4,7,9,10,3,5,1,4,5]
max_min(lista)
```

**resultado**

```
El numero menor es: 1 en el orden 8 y el numero mayor es: 10 en el orden 5
```

Comment: GRACIAS A TODOS :)

Comment: De nada, siempre es preferible aceptar o votar a favor la respuesta solo si soluciona tu problema